# How to navigate to child routes within a dynamic (slug) route in SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

I have the following route structure

```
src/routes/[slug]/results
src/routes/[slug]/about
```

I can't figure out how to link to the routes in SvelteKit. The routes themselves work when I access them through the browser navigation bar.

How can I create a simple links on the [slug] page, that will link to the child routes?

Both below link to the root:

```
<a href="results">results</a>
<a href="/results">results</a>
```

Tried something like below, but that didn't work.

```
<a href="/:slug/results">results</a> 
<a href="/[slug]/results">results</a>
```

I assume it's something similar, but the [SvelteKit documentation on routing](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing) and [advanced routing](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing) don't mention anything related to navigation within dynamic routes.

Answer (score 3):

Would just add the parameter to the link:

```html
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
</script>

<a href="/{$page.params.slug}/results">Results</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out another way too (based on starter documentation, see my own answer on this topic). This seems a bit more direct, although when loading data it's not much effort to add the slug key. Thanks for pointing to '$app/stores'.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a bit [hidden in the documents](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout) (and I'm a starter, so not fully aware of all the concepts yet).

In +page.js:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export function load({ params }) {
  return {
        slug: params.slug
  };
}
```

In +page.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let data;
</script>
<a href="/{data.slug}/result">results</a>
<a href="/{data.slug}/share">share</a>
```